# iterate over dictionary and calculate values using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to iterate over `df2` and multiply `est7wks` value with the corresponding mean in the dictionary `product_mean` if the product line is a global line, else return the `forecast` value.

```py
product_mean = {
    'GROCERY': 1.94,
    'DRINKS': 1.57,
    'PHONES': 2.08
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        'Description': 'cornflakes', 
        'department': 'GROCERY',
        'est_7wks': 2043,
        'Product_Line': 'Global-Line',
        'forecast': 'pending'
    },
    {
        'Description': 'coca-cola',
        'department': 'DRINKS',
        'est_7wks': 10500,
        'Product_Line': 'Global-Line',
        'forecast': 'pending'
    },
    {
        'Description': 'iphone 11',
        'department': 'PHONES',
        'est_7wks': 140,
        'Product_Line': 'Diamond-Line',
        'forecast': 'pending'
    }
])
```

My code.

```py
def section_dep(product_mean, department, est_7wks, Product_Line, forecast):
    for k,v in product_mean.items():
        if department == k and Product_Line = 'Diamond-Line':
            return est_7wks*v
        else:
            return forecast

df['forecast'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: section_dep(
        product_mean,
        x['department'],
        x['est_7wks'],
        x['Product_Line'], 
        x['forecast']
    ),
    axis=1
)
```

It works but only return variables for the first in the dictionary item `GROCERY`. Other departments such as `DRINKS` and `PHONES` don't come back with a value.

Comment: What is product_mean? Its not clear from your qn what you are trying to do

Comment: @SerialLazer product_mean is the dictionary containing various mean values for the 'department'. This is the value i wish to be multiplied by 'est7wks' if the condition holds

Comment: Make sure you also add the output you got and specify the exact problem with it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). Using this method you don't need to iterate over the rows in your DataFrame, which will be much faster.

```py
# Make a boolean mask for "Diamond-Line"
diamond_mask = df2["Product_Line"].eq("Diamond-Line")

# Create a conditions list from product_mean
conditions = [(diamond_mask & df2["department"].eq(k)) for k in product_mean]

# Create a choices list from product_mean
choices = [df2["est_7wks"] * v for k, v in product_mean.items()]

# Use np.select, with a default of forecast
df2["res"] = np.select(condlist=conditions, choicelist=choices, default=df2["forecast"])
```

Output:

```py
Out[14]:   Description department  est_7wks      Product_Line forecast      res
         0  cornflakes    GROCERY      2043  Global-Line-Line  pending  pending
         1   coca-cola     DRINKS     10500  Global-Line-Line  pending  pending
         2   iphone 11     PHONES       140      Diamond-Line  pending    291.2
```

Comment: what if i wanted to do this for multiple conditions, say silver_mask =df2["Product_Line"].eq("Silver-Line")
and then i have product_mean 2 with different values.  can you help factor in a second condition with silver_mask and provide a code to run them simultaneously

Comment: It would be the same code but using your `silver_mask` instead. If you want to use them both simultaneously you are heading towards a large combinations of conditions. You should make your question clearer about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

`section_dep` function should be:

```py
def section_dep(product_mean, department, est_7wks, Product_Line, forecast):
    if Product_Line == 'Global-Line-Line' and department in product_mean:
        return est_7wks * product_mean[department]
    else:
        return forecast
```

Comment: product_mean is a dictionary with keys and values as indicated above

Comment: Yes, that’s why I use the `in` operator and the `[]` operator to test for the key and get the value.